# The answer should be in the form of a question, like jeopardy but with a bit more ~fantasy~

Tags: wordplay, pattern, lateral-thinking, video-games, word-game

> The answer to the first is not bad or inferior.
>
> The answer to the second is not noise or agitation.
>
> The answer to the third is not evil or corruption.
>
> The answer to the fourth is not discord or disharmony.
>
> The answer to the fifth is not pessimistic.

This is intended to be a difficult puzzle.  I will periodically add hints to try to make it easier.  Good luck, my brother.

Hint #1

> I didn't want to take PerpetualJ's edit as what is outside the yellow contains the first hint

Hint #2

> The answer to the fifth is also not optimistic, my brother

Hint #3

> This knowledge is pretty specific and im either looking for the 5 correct questions, or the game in which they all have in common

Hint #4

> credit to @Joe-You-Know - the second line could also be written as 'Silence, my brother'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Game

> **Skyrim**. The real hint is "my brother", which is the only hint "outside yellow" (spoilers bar color). This is a recurrent phrase used by The Dark Brotherhood. The Black Door asks the Dragonborn 5 questions in the form of riddles to allow him/her to enter.

Questions

The answer to the first is not bad or inferior.

> "**What is the flavour of fear?**" (Sublime, my brother. It is more or less the opposite of bad and inferior)

The answer to the second is not noise or agitation.

> "**What is the music of life?**" (Silence, my brother. It is the opposite of noise or agitation.)

The answer to the third is not evil or corruption.

> "**What is life's greatest illusion?**" (Innocence, my brother. It is the opposite of corruption, and to some extent evil.)

The answer to the fourth is not discord or disharmony.

> "**What is the gift of death?**" (Solace, my brother. It is the opposite of discord.)

The answer to the fifth is not pessimistic.

> "**What is the color of night?**" (Sanguine, my brother. It is the opposite of pessimistic, when referring to a person.)

Misc

> It seems all antonyms where taken from thesaurus.com. Just an observation I came across while solving the puzzle. Also, the questions are not in the order The Black Door asks them, which might make the puzzle slightly more difficult.

Comment: Darn it! I was posting this same answer! Good job +1

Comment: Nice job, I felt like the 'my brother' clues were a little too much but my next hint was going to ask Talos for guidance.

Comment: The Talos clue would probably be too much information, I believe. It was a really enjoyable puzzle!

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is my attempt at this.

The answer to the first is not bad or inferior.

> What is okay?

The answer to the second is not noise or agitation.

> What is silence?

The answer to the third is not evil or corruption.

> What is purity?

The answer to the fourth is not discord or disharmony.

> What is harmony?

The answer to the fifth is not pessimistic.

> What is realistic?

I don't know why, but I think the game you are referring to is,

> The Silent Hill series of games.

Comment: rot13(Gur nafjre gb gur frpbaq dhrfgvba vf fvyrapr == Gur nafjre gb gur frpbaq dhrfgvba vf abg abvfr be ntvgngvba.)

  So you are on the right path for finding out the answers but the question and game is still wrong

Comment: Wait, so the second one is right?

Comment: Its wrong but you made some progress so I added another hint about it